# problem passing multiple parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parameters, messaging

[EDIT] ===PROBLEM SOLVED====

====JUST AFTER I SUBMITTED I SAW THE OBVIOUS====

Wrong name in the call "andUpdate", should be "andWriteRead:". Just realize i am a blind person.

Hi,

I am passing multiple parameters in messages in other parts of my code without problem but with this i have problem. It works perfectly passing one parameter but not with two. I would guess it is just me who doesn't see the forrest because of the trees. Could someone please look at this and tell me what i am doing wrong?

The following works:

message:

```
[setupQuestions questionsNumbersPLIST:diffLvls];
```

Target object.

.h:

```
- (void)questionsNumbersPLIST:(NSMutableArray *)questionsList;
```

.m:

```
- (void)questionsNumbersPLIST:(NSMutableArray *)questionsList {
```

> =========================================

Then i try to pass multiple parameters like this:

message:

```
[setupQuestions questionsNumbersPLIST:diffLvls andUpdate:myString];
```

Target object

.h:

```
- (void)questionsNumbersPLIST:(NSMutableArray *)questionsList andWriteRead:(NSString *)update;
```

.m:

```
- (void)questionsNumbersPLIST:(NSMutableArray *)questionsList andWriteRead:(NSString *)update;
```

I get:

> warning: (Messages without a matching method signature

Answer (score 2):

You named your method `quetionsNumbersPLIST:andWriteRead:` so you have to call it that way, you can't just arbitrarily rename it. So to call it:

`[setupQuestions questionsNumbersPLIST:diffLvls andWriteRead:myString];`